# Exclude directories from inotifywait

Tags: regex

Doing an `inotifywait` to watch a directory, and trying to exclude **all** subdirectories from being watched while **not** excluding the files.

```
inotifywait -r -q --exclude <pattern> dir/
```

What to put in `<pattern>`? Manual for `inotifywait` specifies:

```
--exclude <pattern>
Do not process any events whose filename matches the specified POSIX extended regular expression, case sensitive.
```

There's no `-type` flag like in `find`. I've tried `(^/)` but that seems to exclude everything.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `--exclude` option only acts on filenames, there's no direct way to do it. You could try round-about ways like using `find` to print the name of all directories:

```
inotifywait --exclude "echo -n (;$(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%P|');echo )" .
```

Note that I didn't specify `-r`, since that will cause newly created subdirectories to be watched too.

This might break with some special characters.

---

You could also try:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '@%P\n' > list_of_directories
inotifywait --fromfile list_of_directories .
```

`inotifywait` will exclude any files or folders in `list_of_directories` which begin with `@` (all of them do).

---

If you're using `inotifywait` with the recursive option, let `find` list all nested subdirectories as well by removing the `-maxdepth` restriction (also applies to the first command):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '@%P\n' > list_of_directories
inotifywait --fromfile list_of_directories . -r
```

The `-mindepth` is retained to prevent `find` from matching `.`, and thus excluding the current directory as well.

Comment: Thanks! But the last version of `find` will not catch subdirectories within subdirectories, I just tried it to confirm. I need it to catch *all* directories and ignore *all* files. In other words, I just want `inotifywait` to watch changes to files and nothing else. Seemed simple. Oh well.

Comment: @Sqerstet since I hadn't included the recursive option, that seemed fine. If not, you can simply remove the `-maxdepth` option to let `find` find all nested subdirectories.

Comment: Didn't work until I added `\n` after `@%P`

Comment: are you sure no directories?.. I just tried this ```inotifywait -mr --exclude '(.chromium)' -e modify -e create -e delete  ~/.config``` from https://serverfault.com/questions/403874/inotifywait-usage-and-exclude, and it worked. Normally its flooded with junk from Chrome.

Comment: @alchemy I think what I meant is that there's no direct regex to exclude subdirectories but include files (e.g., when you're looping on files in a shell, you can do `foo*/` to expand only to subdirectories and there's no equivalent here - all that pattern gets is the name, and there's no way to tell from the name whether it's a directory).

Answer (score 5):

Just use `--exclude '/\..+'`. This ignores all files that start with a dot.

(The `.+` part is so that it does not exclude your base folder).

Answer (score 4):

`inotifywait` only checks subdirectories because of the parameter `-r`.
Call it **without** that parameter and it won't watch subdirectories.

Comment: Apologies, my question was not clear. I want to exclude the directories but not the files. Question updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
/usr/bin/inotifywait -mrq --format  '%Xe %w%f' -e modify,create,delete,attrib,close_write,move --exclude '^./workspace' ./ | while read file; do
   # do something
done
```

Replace the *workspace* to your directory name.

Answer (score 1):

**I can confirm, that `--exclude 'node_modules'` does the job for me, also if `node_modules` is a subfolder.**

```bash
while inotifywait -rqq -e close_write --exclude 'node_modules' "$1"; do $2;$3;$4; done
```

also tested in this:

```bash
inotifywait --recursive --monitor --format "%e %w%f" \
  --event modify,move,create,delete  --exclude 'node_modules'  ./ |
  while read changed; do
    sleep .2 && ./devrun
  done
```